# Override ForeignKey relationship in child model?

Tags: python, django, models

I am trying to do some [model inheritance](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/models/#model-inheritance)  in django 1.7 and I am wondering if there is a way to over ride foreign key fields? I have a schema for a curriculum and I would like to be able to define multiple curriculums with the same features (pages, questions, levels, etc.)

Here is my code:

http://hastebin.com/ixekepolik.py (Lines 117, 118, 120, 121, 123, 129 and 131)

I'm getting this error currently:

```
django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Local field 'level' in class 'HVPage' clashes with field of similar name from base class 'Page'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I read [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/models/#s-field-name-hiding-is-not-permitted), it is disallowed at present (and in django 1.7)

> Field name “hiding” is not permitted¶
>
> In normal Python class inheritance, it is permissible for a child
>   class to override any attribute from the parent class. In Django, this
>   is not permitted for attributes that are Field instances (at least,
>   not at the moment). If a base class has a field called author, you
>   cannot create another model field called author in any class that
>   inherits from that base class.
>
> Overriding fields in a parent model leads to difficulties in areas
>   such as initializing new instances (specifying which field is being
>   initialized in Model.**init**) and serialization. These are features
>   which normal Python class inheritance doesn’t have to deal with in
>   quite the same way, so the difference between Django model inheritance
>   and Python class inheritance isn’t arbitrary.
>
> This restriction only applies to attributes which are Field instances.
>   Normal Python attributes can be overridden if you wish. It also only
>   applies to the name of the attribute as Python sees it: if you are
>   manually specifying the database column name, you can have the same
>   column name appearing in both a child and an ancestor model for
>   multi-table inheritance (they are columns in two different database
>   tables).
>
> Django will raise a FieldError if you override any model field in any
>   ancestor model.

Comment: @broinjc has your question been answered?